# change style component when state isn't null in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try add in React red border for my input, when login doesn't exist. I've come up with a way that adds a class to the input, but I think it's not good practice. How can I write it better?

```
  {[
    loginError ? (
      <Fragment>
        <input
          className={classNames(
            classes.formItem,
            classes.formError,
          )}
          placeholder="write number"
          name="login"
          type="text"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <div className={classes.textError}>{loginError}</div>
      </Fragment>
    ) : (
      <input
        className={classes.formItem}
        placeholder="write number"
        name="login"
        type="text"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    ),
  ]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add classes conditionally using classnames when there is an error a also render the error message. Further you can remove redundancy form the above code like

```
{
     <Fragment>
        <input
          className={classNames(
            classes.formItem, {
            [classes.formError]: loginError
          })}
          placeholder="write number"
          name="login"
          type="text"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        {loginError ? <div className={classes.textError}>{loginError}</div>: null}
    </Fragment>
}
```